# Creating a function in R but getting a replacement has length zero error

Tags: r

I tried to create a function f and create the function so when a value x is inserted, it spits out a function f from y.But, when I try to run the code to plot, it gives me an error that says that my y_value has no length.

```
f <- function(x){
  if (x<0){
   print(y_values<-x*x*x)
  }
  if(x>0 & x<=1){
    print(y_values<-x*x)
  }
  if(x>1){
    print(y_values<-sqrt(x))
  }

}
```

```
x_values <- seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)
y_values <- rep(NA, length(x_values))
for (i in seq_along(x_values)) {
  x <- x_values[i]
  y_values[i] <- f(x)
}

# output
plot(x_values, y_values, type = "l")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. From `?print`

   > ‘print’ prints its argument and returns it *invisibly* (via
   >    ‘invisible(x)’)

   So all your function `f` does is *print* the values to the console (instead of returning them).
2. As per your definition of `f`, the function does not know how to deal with `x=0`; so this will create a problem when you store the output of `f(0)` later.

We can fix these issues by slightly altering `f` as

```
    f <- function(x) {
      y_values <- NA
      if (x<0){
       y_values<-x*x*x
      }
      if(x>0 & x<=1){
        y_values<-x*x
      }
      if(x>1){
        y_values<-sqrt(x)
      }
      return(y_values)
  }
```

Then

```
x_values <- seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)
y_values <- rep(NA, length(x_values))
for (i in seq_along(x_values)) {
  x <- x_values[i]
  y_values[i] <- f(x)
}

plot(x_values, y_values, type = "l")
```

[image]

---

You could also use `Vectorize` to obtain a *vectorised* function `f2`, which allows you to pass `x_values` as a vector, thereby avoiding the explicit `for` loop:

```
f2 <- Vectorize(f)
x_values <- seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)
y_values <- f2(x_values)
```

The resulting plot is the same.

Comment: f isn't really vectorized with those if statements in there

Comment: @Dason Ouch, you're very right. Sloppy response from my side. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you explore other methods for coding something like this:

here is one option that doesn't use a for loop. If you are simply working on using for loops then the fix Mauritus Evers made should work for you.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(x_values = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) %>% 
  mutate(y_values = case_when(x_values < 0 ~ x_values^3,
                              x_values>=0 & x_values<=1 ~ x_values^2,
                              x_values>1 ~ sqrt(x_values))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x_values, y_values)) + geom_point()
```

note that I changed your code to produce output when x_value = 0.